# Cannot open "Options" page for Project in Delphi

Tags: delphi, error-handling, access-violation

[image: Error message]

This happens only in one application. That application is succesfuly compiled, but Options page (Project -> Options...) are blocked. I have no idea what this error message means. 
So, I need yours help.

Comment: What does clicking the `Details` button show you? The stack trace here might be helpful; there's certainly not enough information in what you've posted to use. The `read of address 00000000` indicates it's trying to use an object that isn't created, but we can't tell why that might be happening based on a picture of a generic access violation and a "This happens only in one application" statement. :-)

Comment: When I get an error like this I close Delphi then restart it.  Sometimes I have to kill Delphi via task manager.

Comment: The other option is to simply close Delphi, rename the `.dproj` file, and then double-click the `.dpr` file. The IDE will re-generate a new `.dproj` file based on the defaults.

Comment: @Ken White, thanks to you Options page are now unblocked! ;-) P.S. I have never learned english, and because of that my question is not as clear as it should be.

Comment: Glad I could help. :-) I posted as an answer in case it's useful to someone in the future who has the same type of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when something like this happens, the project file has become corrupted in some way. (The error message `Read of address 00000000` indicates that an object has been referenced before it's created, and that typically indicates something's gone terribly wrong somewhere.)

The easiest way I've found to deal with this is simply to shut down the IDE, and then rename your project (`.dproj`) file. Then double-click your `.dpr` (project source) file, and the IDE will regenerate a new project file for you based on your default configuration. This usually solves the problem with the access violation and allows you to edit the project options again.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is already answered and the answer is accepted but, we found here that the same error occurs in Delphi 5/7 in windows 8+ when DEP is activated and Delphi IDE is not in exception list.

To solve this you need to do one of these:

- Disable dep
- Set Delphi as a exception to DEP